# Import local folder in bitbucket

Tags: git, version-control

I'm currently working on a project with some classmates and I want to share code with them, they are not changing the code, they just need it to see how far I've gotten with my work.

I tried creating a repository on github for that, but they aren't private unless you pay, which I don't want to. I also tried bitbucket, where I can't import local files, only a already existing github repository.

How can I add local files in Bitbucket OR where can I create private repositorys.

I don't know much about programming yet and the whole version-control and git topics are new to me.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart That's on github? Because I can't make a private repo on github, only on bitbucket but I can't import a local folder on bitbucket, only a git repo. which wouldn't be private then ...

Comment: @Seraphina Does the files in local folder already in a local git repo or not?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT I don't think so. As I said I don't know anything about git yet. I tried reading some tutorials, as mentioned in the answers but I don't understand it.

Comment: @Seraphina I added an answer with the way to check if the local folder in a git repo or not, and the detail steps to push the folder to bitbucket. You can have a try.

Comment: @Seraphina Have you get the answer which helps you solve the problem? If yes, can you mark the answer by clicking √ symbol on the left of the answer? And it will also benefit other members who meet similar questions.

Answer (score 7):

To import the local folder to bitbucket repo, you can follow below steps.

### Prerequisitions:

1. Install [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) in your local machine
2. Check if the local folder already in a git repo

   In the directory of the folder you want to import to bitbucket repo, execute:

   ```
   git rev-parse --show-toplevel
   ```

   If it shows `not a git reposiroty` that means the local folder has not been managed in git repo. Else, if it shows a parent directory, that means the local folder has been managed in git repo

### Steps to import:

1. Create a local git repo if the local folder not in a local git repo

   As the prerequisition 2 shows, if the local folder has not been managed in a local git repo, then create by below commands (assume the folder `myfolder` is what you want to import, and it’s in `C:\test\example\myfolder`):

   ```
   # in the directory C:\test\example
   git init
   git add .
   git commit -am 'initial commit'
   ```

   Else, if the folder has already managed in a git repo, skip this step.
2. Add bitbucket repo as remote for the local git repo

   Use the command `git remote add origin bitbucket repo URL>` to add the new created bitbucket repo as a remote `origin` for the local git repo. Such as:

   ```
   git remote add origin https://accountu@bitbucket.org/account/reponame.git
   ```
3. Push changes to bitbucket repo

   Use the command to push local commit(s) to bitbucket repo:

   ```
   git push -u origin master
   ```

Now the local folder myfolder is pushed to the bitbucket repo successful.

Answer (score 1):

First, must init repository in your main project folder.

```
git init
```

Add your project files to the Git repo -

```
git add .

git commit -m "first commit"
```

Then create repository on BitBucket.org. Also your must create pair of keys for git client, so you can push changes.

After adding public key to BB,
Rub this:

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:<org or user>/<repo name>.git
```

Where:

- `<org or user>` use your Bitbucket account's name (or team/organisation),
- `<repo name>`user repository name.

Example:
https://bitbucket.org/user/simple-repository - link to User's repository, called "simple repository".

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:user/simple-repository.git
```

I almost forgot. After that run:

```
git push -u origin master
```

This will push all your files to remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn something related to some [Git Basics](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository). After that, you will know that a BitBucket repository is not only that, created by importing a GitHub repo, but also can, create by a local folder.

Also, since you mentioned "classmates", maybe [GitHub Student Pack](https://education.github.com/pack) which have unlimited private repository can be your choice, too.